# How to load all controls added to a word document (Microsoft Office Interop Word)?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, backend

I am using  Microsoft.Office.Interop to open, manipulate and save a Word document file (.doc).
I can get all Text contents but no success in loading added controls (i.e. TextBoxes) in the opened word document.

I get the text using following command

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass oWordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
oWordDoc.Activate();
oWordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph(); 
string test = oWordDoc.Content.Text;
```

How can I have access to all controls included in the base word document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing

> oWordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph();

To

> oWordApp.Selection.WholeStory();

And digging in oWordDoc.shapes, I gained access to all controls.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
    Word.Document oDoc=...;
    foreach (Word.Shape shape in oDoc.Shapes)
        {
           //do some thing with shape
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramin, but the oWordDoc.Shapes.Count() equals to Zero!

Comment: I Got it, using oWordApp.Selection.WholeStory() instead of oWordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph() and using your workaround did the trick.

Comment: How is this answering the question?